# VBA code running but seems to not run the full procedure

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of ChatGPT I have created a VBA code which will remove company acronyms from the names of companies in the column "Company" or column "Name".

I have run the code and no error comes back, yet no result at all on the data. I'm thinking the VBA argumenta are not cycling through correctly. Perhaps currently the procedure ends after the column was found?

```
Sub RemoveValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim valuesToRemove As Variant
Dim value As Variant

' Set your sheet name
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Find the "Company" or "Name" column
Dim targetColIndex As Integer
targetColIndex = 0
On Error Resume Next
targetColIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Company", ws.Rows(1), 0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    targetColIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", ws.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' List the values you want to remove
valuesToRemove = Array("SRL", "S.R.L.; o Ltda. (Solo Chile)", "UG (haftungsbeschränkt)", "San. ve Tic. Ltd. Sti." _
, "India Private Limited", "San. ve Tic A.S.", "(Pvt.) Limited", "GmbH & Co. KG" _
, "GmbH + Co. KG", "GmbH + Co. KG", "spol. s r.o.", "& C. S.n.c.", "Ltda., Lda.", "GmbH  Co KG" _
, "Sp. z o. o.", "(Cty) TNHH", "Sp. z o.o.", "sp. z o.o.", "Sp z o.o.", "(Pty) Ltd", "(Pvt) Ltd", "Co.,Ltd." _
, "CO., LTD.", "CO., LTD.", "Pvt. Ltd.", "Sdn. Bhd.", "Sp. z o.o", "Ltd. Co.", "S. p. A.", "s. r. o.", _
, "CO., LTD", "s.à.r.l.", "Limited", "o Ltda.", "Pte Ltd", "Tic. AS", "sh.p", "Pty Ltd", "d.o.o" _
, "S.r.o.", "D.O.O.", "Ltd.", "LTD.", "S.A.S.", "d.o.o.", "Co. KG", "s.n.c.", "S.R.L.", "S.r.l.", "s.r.l." _
, "s.r.o.", "S.p.A.", "?.?.?.", "?.?.?.", "m.b.H.", "S.p.a.", "a.r.l.", "S.P.A.", "d.o.o", "a. s.", "(PVT)" _
, "Corp.", "Ltda.", "S. A.", "A. S.", "S. L.", "S.r.l", "S.R.L", "d.d.", "a.s.", "GmbH", "B.V.", "A.S.", "Co.," _
, "GmbH", "gmbh", "Inc.", "Lda.", "Ltd.", "N.V.", "MChJ", "S.L.", "Sagl", "SARL", "kft.", "S.A.", "A.S.", "z.s." _
, "SAS", "A/S", "SpA", "LLC", "Ltd", "Lda", "PBC", "Srl", "SRL", "???", "???", "UAB", "SIA", "ApS", "MMC", "A.S." _
, "Spa", "AS.", "S.A", "srl", "AS", "AG", "AB", "BV", "BV", "bv", "LC", "KG", "SA", "GK", "PT", "Oy", "OÜ", "SL", "SE", "NV")


' Go through each cell in the range
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, targetColIndex), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, targetColIndex).End(xlUp))

End Sub
```

I have tried to edit my Array to something very simple such as
    `valuesToRemove = Array(ABC`) to see if this part of the code is the problem. It still runs good but does not remove the ABC value from the data.

Any clue?

Comment: I wouldn't put that list into your code.  Instead create a table with the list of values to remove and iterate through that.  That way if you need to modify the list, you don't need to edit your code (much easier to support).

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually `.Replace` the values in question, with a loop over `valuesToRemove`:

Note that you have an extra comma in `valuesToRemove`. Also, some array elements contain the special character `?`, which should be escaped with `~`. That is, unless you want the special character ... which you haven't specified.

```
' Remove the extra comma at the end of the 5th line
valuesToRemove = Array("SRL", "S.R.L.; o Ltda. (Solo Chile)", "UG (haftungsbeschränkt)", "San. ve Tic. Ltd. Sti." _
, "India Private Limited", "San. ve Tic A.S.", "(Pvt.) Limited", "GmbH & Co. KG" _
, "GmbH + Co. KG", "GmbH + Co. KG", "spol. s r.o.", "& C. S.n.c.", "Ltda., Lda.", "GmbH  Co KG" _
, "Sp. z o. o.", "(Cty) TNHH", "Sp. z o.o.", "sp. z o.o.", "Sp z o.o.", "(Pty) Ltd", "(Pvt) Ltd", "Co.,Ltd." _
, "CO., LTD.", "CO., LTD.", "Pvt. Ltd.", "Sdn. Bhd.", "Sp. z o.o", "Ltd. Co.", "S. p. A.", "s. r. o." _
, "CO., LTD", "s.à.r.l.", "Limited", "o Ltda.", "Pte Ltd", "Tic. AS", "sh.p", "Pty Ltd", "d.o.o" _
, "S.r.o.", "D.O.O.", "Ltd.", "LTD.", "S.A.S.", "d.o.o.", "Co. KG", "s.n.c.", "S.R.L.", "S.r.l.", "s.r.l." _
, "s.r.o.", "S.p.A.", "?.?.?.", "?.?.?.", "m.b.H.", "S.p.a.", "a.r.l.", "S.P.A.", "d.o.o", "a. s.", "(PVT)" _
, "Corp.", "Ltda.", "S. A.", "A. S.", "S. L.", "S.r.l", "S.R.L", "d.d.", "a.s.", "GmbH", "B.V.", "A.S.", "Co.," _
, "GmbH", "gmbh", "Inc.", "Lda.", "Ltd.", "N.V.", "MChJ", "S.L.", "Sagl", "SARL", "kft.", "S.A.", "A.S.", "z.s." _
, "SAS", "A/S", "SpA", "LLC", "Ltd", "Lda", "PBC", "Srl", "SRL", "???", "???", "UAB", "SIA", "ApS", "MMC", "A.S." _
, "Spa", "AS.", "S.A", "srl", "AS", "AG", "AB", "BV", "BV", "bv", "LC", "KG", "SA", "GK", "PT", "Oy", "OÜ", "SL", "SE", "NV")


Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(valuesToRemove) To UBound(valuesToRemove)
    rng.Replace Replace(valuesToRemove(i), "?", "~?"), "", xlPart
Next
```

Side note:

Here's an approach using `Application.Match` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

```
Dim targetColIndex As Variant
targetColIndex = Application.Match("Company", ws.Rows(1), 0)

If IsError(targetColIndex) Then
    targetColIndex = Application.Match("Name", ws.Rows(1), 0)
End If

If IsError(targetColIndex) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the suggestion. 
So I added this piece of VBA code at the bottom on the script.

`Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(valuesToRemove) to Ubound(valuesToRemove)
    rng.Replace valuesToRemove(i), "", xlPart
Next`

Running this had an impact on the company name values.
However, the impact was negative. All names cut severely cut only one or two character remain in each row. Sometimes the entire name has been erased.
I'm wondering what happened there.

Comment: The issue is the same as above when using the `Application.Match`

Comment: I've made another edit to the first snippet. Probably best to escape every instance of `?`. Or, do you want to pattern match here?

Comment: Thanks.
So no the `?` are mistakes.
I need to clean them out in fact.

Comment: `?` is a special character. If you want to match the literal character `?`, then you have to escape it with `~`.

Comment: So used your new edit into the Module.

I get an error:
"Run-time error 13: Type mismatch"

It seems it is not liking the             `rng.Replace Replace(valuesToRemove(i), "?", "~?"), "", xlPart`

I think its easier I just remove all the `?` from the Array

Comment: Did you fix the extra comma issue?  `' Remove the extra comma at the end of the 5th line`... That caused a type mismatch for me. I don't think the `?` are the cause of a type mismatch. You have `"s. r. o.", _
, "CO., LTD",`... two commas between those elements.

Comment: Hey. You were right. I have added back the special characters and your piece of VBA to escape the special characters.

I have removed the the extra Comma. Its much better now.
Still some names are getting cut into like it shouldn't

For example
`Assembly Ventures LLC` became `mbly Ventures`
`Asas Aluminyum ve Tic. A.S.` became `A Aluminyum ve Tic. `
`Ascorium Industries`  became `corium Industries`

It seems one of the string in the Array is impacting those. It there a way to modify the code so it does not work on the beginning text in the cell?

Comment: You could potentially use regex or `Split` here, but this is an entirely different approach (will use `Replace`, not `Range.Replace`)

Comment: Ok. Maybe that could be better. I'll have to take some time and re-write this fully with this new approach.


To help me understand the piece of VBA code you added 
`Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(valuesToRemove) To UBound(valuesToRemove)
    rng.Replace Replace(valuesToRemove(i), "?", "~?"), "", xlPart`

could you explain what does piece does?

Comment: That's looping the array and calling `Replace` on the `rng` with each of the array elements successively. If an array element contains `?`, that gets changed to `~?` first.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Regular Expression. This matches patterns at the end of the string.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveValues()

    ' List the values you want to remove
    Dim valuesToRemove As Variant
    valuesToRemove = Array("SRL", "S.R.L.; o Ltda. (Solo Chile)", "UG (haftungsbeschränkt)", "San. ve Tic. Ltd. Sti." _
    , "India Private Limited", "San. ve Tic A.S.", "(Pvt.) Limited", "GmbH & Co. KG" _
    , "GmbH + Co. KG", "GmbH + Co. KG", "spol. s r.o.", "& C. S.n.c.", "Ltda., Lda.", "GmbH  Co KG" _
    , "Sp. z o. o.", "(Cty) TNHH", "Sp. z o.o.", "sp. z o.o.", "Sp z o.o.", "(Pty) Ltd", "(Pvt) Ltd", "Co.,Ltd." _
    , "CO., LTD.", "CO., LTD.", "Pvt. Ltd.", "Sdn. Bhd.", "Sp. z o.o", "Ltd. Co.", "S. p. A.", "s. r. o." _
    , "CO., LTD", "s.à.r.l.", "Limited", "o Ltda.", "Pte Ltd", "Tic. AS", "sh.p", "Pty Ltd", "d.o.o" _
    , "S.r.o.", "D.O.O.", "Ltd.", "LTD.", "S.A.S.", "d.o.o.", "Co. KG", "s.n.c.", "S.R.L.", "S.r.l.", "s.r.l." _
    , "s.r.o.", "S.p.A.", "m.b.H.", "S.p.a.", "a.r.l.", "S.P.A.", "d.o.o", "a. s.", "(PVT)" _
    , "Corp.", "Ltda.", "S. A.", "A. S.", "S. L.", "S.r.l", "S.R.L", "d.d.", "a.s.", "GmbH", "B.V.", "A.S.", "Co.," _
    , "GmbH", "gmbh", "Inc.", "Lda.", "Ltd.", "N.V.", "MChJ", "S.L.", "Sagl", "SARL", "kft.", "S.A.", "A.S.", "z.s." _
    , "SAS", "A/S", "SpA", "LLC", "Ltd", "Lda", "PBC", "Srl", "SRL", "UAB", "SIA", "ApS", "MMC", "A.S." _
    , "Spa", "AS.", "S.A", "srl", "AS", "AG", "AB", "BV", "BV", "bv", "LC", "KG", "SA", "GK", "PT", "Oy", "OÜ", "SL", "SE", "NV")

    ' sort longest first
    SortByLen(valuesToRemove)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c, ch
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim s As String
    
    ' Set your sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Find the "Company" or "Name" column
    c = Application.Match("Company", ws.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsError(c) Then
       c = Application.Match("Name", ws.Rows(1), 0)
       If IsError(c) Then
            MsgBox "Error - Could not find column Name or Company", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
       End If
    End If
    
    ' test data
    'For i = 1 To UBound(valuesToRemove)
    '    Cells(i + 1, c) = "company name  " & valuesToRemove(i - 1)
    'Next
    
    ' escape special characters in regex pattern
    For i = 0 To UBound(valuesToRemove) - 1
        For Each ch In Array(".", "[", "]", "(", ")", "+")
            valuesToRemove(i) = Replace(valuesToRemove(i), ch, "\" & ch)
        Next
    Next
    
    ' build regular expression
    Dim regEx As Object, m As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = " +(" & Join(valuesToRemove, "|") & ")$" ' $=line ending
        'Debug.Print .Pattern
    End With
    
    ' clean data
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            s = Trim(Cells(i, c))
            If regEx.test(s) Then
                'Set m = regEx.Execute(s)
                'Cells(i, c + 1) = m(0) ' use spare column to see match
                Cells(i, c) = regEx.Replace(s, "")
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " lines changed", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub SortByLen(ByRef ar)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tmp As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(ar)
            If Len(ar(j)) > Len(ar(i)) Then
                tmp = ar(j)
                ar(j) = ar(i)
                ar(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for the code provided.
It seems a more advance solution. 

I tried running it. I really like the  message at the end which confirms the amount of rows which have been edited.

Generally it works well. I do have some values that were not removed:
"Co.", "Co.Ltd", Co. Ltd." (with a space) "A.Ş."

Also some values are being cut in half "SE & Co. KG" the "Co. KG" gets removed the rest remains.

Would adding those values in the Array be sufficient? Is there a way we can prioritize the array to start looking at longer string of text first?

Comment: @AlexandreBrandt OK see update, I have sorted the array longest first. Adding the missing values should solve the ones not removed.

Comment: Thank you.

I see that you code now has a second Sub to sort the lengths.
I'm wondering, if I want to wrap this Macro with a MsgBox

`' Message box to user
Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete columns ?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")
    
' Run only if Yes
If Answer = vbYes Then`

And then close it with

`End If`

How would I do that? Do I need to wrap only the first sub and let the Second sub run directly after?

Comment: @AlexandreBrandt The first sub will call the sort sub, you don't have to run it separately.